# How to replace dynamically replace keys of a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace the `item` with `object` for the keys in a Python dictionary. I was wondering if re would be required. Or if I can use the replace function? How would I go about doing this?

What I have:

```
mydictionary = {
    'item_1': [7,19],
    'item_2': [0,3],
    'item_3': [54,191],
    'item_4': [41,43],
}
```

What I want:

```
mydictionary = {
    'object_1': [7,19],
    'object_2': [0,3],
    'object_3': [54,191],
    'object_4': [41,43],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mydictionary = {
    key.replace("item", "object"): value for key, value in mydictionary.items()
}
```

The syntax uses dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary based on the old dictionary but with a modification in old dictionary keys.
 Also `re` module could be used instead of the string `replace` method but since there is no regular expression/pattern involved `re` module will only complicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the keys in a dictionary, so you will need to create a new dictionary. The most concise way to do this is probably comprehensions. First we, need to replace every string "item" with "object" in our old keys, then create a new dictionary with the same values. This should do it:

```
# Get keys
oldkeys = list(mydictionary.keys())
# Change "item" to "object"
newkeys = [s.replace('item', 'object') for s in oldkeys]
# Get values
vals = list(mydictionary.values())
# Create new dictionary by iterating over both newkeys and vals
newdictionary = {k: v for k, v in zip(newkeys, vals)}
```

`newdictionary` now looks like this:

```
{'object_1': [7, 19], 'object_2': [0, 3], 'object_3': [54, 191], 'object_4': [41, 43]}
```

Note that you could combine this into one comprehension with `mydictionary.items()` to get the key and value pairs as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change a key in a dictionary. The only way to replace it is to create a new dictionary or, add a new key and delete the old key.

The code below uses dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary.

```
mydictionary = {
    'item_1': [7,19],
    'item_2': [0,3],
    'item_3': [54,191],
    'item_4': [41,43],
}

mydictionary = {f"object_{index}": mydictionary[value] for index, value in enumerate(mydictionary, 1)}
```

output:

```
{'object_1': [7, 19], 'object_2': [0, 3], 'object_3': [54, 191], 'object_4': [41, 43]}
```

Comment: This will work only if the OP uses Python 3.7 or newer, and if the items insertion order is in ascending. Insert `item_2` before `item_1` and this will produce the wrong results.